# Finding duplicate characters in a string using for loops in Python:

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I have a simple question. First of all I want to say that the code I used below works perfectly fine for the purpose of finding duplicate characters in a string (although there might be better solutions to that problem without a doubt). But I struggle to understand why i need to declare the count variable in the first for loop after having declared it in the function already, because if I don't declare it in the for loop as well, the program will not work properly... :/

```
def hasDuplicates(s):
   count = 0
   for i in range(0, len(s)):
       count = 0
       for j in range(i+1, len(s)):
           if (s[i] == s[j]):
               count += 1
       if (count == 1):
           print(s[i])
```

Sorry if it is a silly question, I'm new to programming so thanks for the help! :)

Comment: the 2nd count=0 isn't simply declaring it, its also resetting the value back to zero in every loop

Comment: As far as I can tell, the first `count=0` is unnecessary.

Comment: NB. your code is very inefficient as you search the string for the duplicates again at each step. Better use [@Mhmd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69315599/16343464)'s approach with Counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not declaring the variable inside the loop, you're *assigning* to it. This is needed because with out it after the first iteration of the outer loop your counter will retain it's value. Take the following string: `aarron`. After the first loop `count` will retain the value of `1`. When searching for the string `s` this becomes a problem since the final value will be `2`. I would suggest an edit to your code, however, since it doesn't handle strings that have more than one duplicate, such as `aaron a`. Consider something something a little more compact such as

```
def hasDuplicates(s):
    for c in s:
        if s.count(c) > 1:
            print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

your function is just complicated for no reasons, this is a good example you can follow:

```
from collections import Counter

s = "Hello"
counts = Counter(s)

for character, count in counts.most_common():
    print(character, '-', count)
```

and then you can continue if count over 1 then do something